# wordpress fail to connect to mysql using defined constants

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Fail to connect to my DB using the word-pres defined constants

i don’t understand what am i doing wrong

my code snippet :

```
require_once("wp-config.php");
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS); 
if (!$link) {die('it didn’t connect' . mysql_error());} 
echo 'this worked!'; 
mysql_close($link);
```

how can i check that the variables im using have data in them ?

this shows that it isn’t working (output is "it didn’t connect")

what am i doing wrong !!!!???!!!

please help

Comment: did you try to echo the variables and check what is in them ??

Comment: Use the var_dump function to display the values.. e.g. var_dump(DB_HOST); die;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

There is not variable name `DB_PASS`; it is `DB_PASSWORD`.  The var_dump showed that it was empty!

```
require_once("wp-config.php");
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD); 
if (!$link) {die('it didn’t connect' . mysql_error());} 
echo 'this worked!'; 
mysql_close($link);
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, if you want to confirm that a variable has been set, use `isset( $varname )`.  If you want to confirm the contents of a variable and abort the script, use `die( var_dump( $varname ) )`.

Also, are `DB_HOST`, `DB_USER`, and `DB_PASS` defined constants?  If they're variables, you are missing the `$` prefices.

Answer (score 1):

try to do this

```
`require_once("wp-config.php");
var_dump(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
exit;
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
if (!$link) {die('it didn’t connect' . mysql_error());}
echo 'this worked!';  
mysql_close($link);`
```

And check if the variables have the correct data.

Comment: thanks for the help problem was with DB_PASSWORD (not DB_PASS)